# C++ Read in some (not all) only data from an input file to add to a record

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I currently have a CSV file with data like this:

Name...Hair...Eggs...Tall...Water...Land...Domestic

Appl.......1.........0........1........0..........0.............1

Dams.....1.........1........0........0..........1.............1

Eons......0.........1........0........1..........1.............0

Where 0 is false and 1 is true. I'm only interested in reading in the objects Name, Tall, and Domestic, which I will be adding to a record. So far I have

```
    ifstream inFile("file_name.csv");

    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "File cannot be opened due to an error." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

  string junk;
  getline(inFile,junk);
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to go about setting up the while loop to skip over the unnecessary data. It just doesn't make sense to do while(inFile >> name >> hair >> eggs >> tall >> water >> land >> domestic)I'm thinking a for loop within the while loop, but I just can't work it out in my head. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

[Pic of above table attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL8Ud.png)

Comment: BTW, modern computers are fast enough that reading all the data from the file is faster than trying to skip the data.  Read in the record and only use the fields you want to use.

Comment: One issue is that file reading has a starting overhead.  Every time you perform a transaction for example, the hard drive has to spin up, the directory tables searched for the file name, the sector and tracks obtained, then the data reading can begin.  So if you break up (as in skipping) you'll have to perform this overhead (unless the track, sector and file position are remembered along the way).  So much easier to the data flowing.

Comment: So what you are saying is, "The space must flow?"

Comment: What I am saying is for best efficiency, keep the stream flowing.  Read as much data per transaction.  Multiple sequential reads are more efficient than repositioning then reading.  More energy will be spent trying to start and stop a stream rather than letting it flow.

Comment: For example, allocate a large buffer, like 1MB, and binary read into the buffer.  After reading, construct your objects from the buffer.  Repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend in these cases that you model each row with a class or struct:

```
struct Record
{
    std::string name;
    int hair;
    int eggs;
    int tall;
    int water;
    int land;
    int domestic;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    input >> name;
    input >> hair;
    /...
    input >> domestic;
    return input;
}
```

By overloading `operator>>` you can simplify your input:

```
std::vector<Record>  database;
Record r;
while (data_file >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

To access the `Name` field:

```
std::cout << database[3].name << "\n";
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your quick response! Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use a class or struct to implement this. This is an implementation for a public object within a derived class that's inheriting from a base class. I'm asked to just do a simple implementation that will allow for adding these specific items to a record.

Comment: I don't understand.  You are not allowed to use a class or struct, yet this is an implementation from a derived class.

Comment: If you can't use a `class` or `struct`, then use parallel arrays.  Remember the concept is to read in one or more records, then extract the fields that you need.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I ended up using getline(stream, variable, delimiter), where the delimiter was a comma (\n for the last item). Turns out TSV files work very different then CSV files, lol. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Mcunning:  if this answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.